# Constructing Context Free Grammar From The Following Regular Expression

Tags: context-free-grammar

Have a look at the expression

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/itiZi.png]

For the above expression I want to construct a context free grammar, the number of occurrences of 'w's have to be equal to (the occurrences of 'k's divided by 2 because 'k' is n * 2 in the language) + (number of occurrences of 'd's which there are m occurances of)

In other words there must be n+m occurrences of 'w'
I've got this so far

> S ---> XYZ
>   X ---> kX|k|Y
>   Y ---> dY|dd|Z
>   Z ---> (here, how do i get m+n occurrences of "w")?

Any suggestions or hints to complete this context free grammar?

Comment: That's not a regular expression.

Comment: You need to create a production that will consume `kk` for every `w` and another that consume `d` for every `w`. You can start from something like `X -> kkXw`. If you can see why this makes sure that the number of `w` will be half the number of `k`, then you should be able to extend this for your entire grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is problematic because you lose the linkage between how many k's you're adding up front and how many w's you need to add later on. Any production which touches the 2n k's must touch w's for this reason; similarly, any production touching the m d's must touch the w's for the same reason.

Look for ways to create these linkages in your language and you can determine what those required productions will look like. An often helpful way of doing this is by rewriting the input and adding parentheses to show the order that things will be handled in. We know we need a linkage between the 2n k's and the w's, and we know we need a link between the m d's and the w's. The d's are closer so we can start there. We can link the d's to the w's by putting parentheses around the d's and enough w's so that we can find a grammar for the enclosed term. By enclosing m w's, we get a simple grammar: odd strings with a k in the middle, d's on the left and w's on the right and the same numbers of d's and w's.

With that handled, we see there's now an easy linkage between the k's and the w's: there are 2n k's and n w's, so we need a production for the same language as before, except we have k's instead of d's and instead of the numbers being the same, we have twice as many k's as w's.

```
  k^(2n) d^m k w^(m+n) d^2
= k^(2n) [d^m k w^m] w^n d^2
= [k^(2n) [d^m k w^m] w^n] d^2
```

We understood the linkages inside out, and now we can write the grammar outside in:

```
S -> Tdd      // handles the d^2 part on the end
T -> kkTw     // recursive part of the term in the outermost brackets
T -> R        // switch to handle the term in the innermost brackets
R -> dRw      // recursive part of the term in the innermost brackets
R -> k        // base case of the term in the innermost brackets
```